# SQL - condensing repeative boolan 'WHEN' statements

Tags: sql-server-2005

please can anyone suggest a way of condensing this code, to reduce its repetitive nature. many thanks

```
    select case
    when c=1 and cs=1 and f=0 and fs=0 then 'FPL02'
    when c=0 and cs=0 and f=1 and fs=1 then 'FPL03'
    when c=1 and cs=0 and f=0 and fs=0 then 'FPL04'
    when c=0 and cs=0 and f=1 and fs=0 then 'FPL05'
    when c=1 and cs=1 and f=1 and fs=1 then 'FPL06'
    when c=1 and cs=1 and f=1 and fs=0 then 'FPL07'
    when c=1 and cs=0 and f=1 and fs=1 then 'FPL08'
    when c=1 and cs=0 and f=1 and fs=0 then 'FPL09'
    when Ab=1 then 'FPL10'
    when cpc=1 and plo=0 then 'FPC01'
    when cpc=0 and plo=1 then 'FPC02'
    when cpc=1 and plo=1 then 'FPC03'
    else 'FPL01' end

    from (select ptmatter, BillLHAbsolute as Ab, BillLHChildren as C, BillLHChildrenSettle as CS, BillLHFinances as F, BillLHFinancesSettle as FS, BillLHCPC as CPC, BillLHPLO as PLO from MatterDataDef) as mmd
    where ptmatter=$matter$
```

Comment: Are FPL02 through FPL09 the only possible combinations, or are there more?  I have an idea to condense the code, but it's probably less grokable than what you have right now.

Comment: There are more, i used the above for illustrative purposes - i'll add the full coding above -- UPDATED: above code is now the full dataset

Comment: Is ab=0 for all combis of FPL02 till FPL09?

Comment: @rene yes, for all combis except FPL10 `Ab=0`, and for clarity FPL10 `c=0 cs=0 f=0 fs=0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that many different conditional statements on different columns, I sincerely doubt you can condense that code while having it still be maintainable by someone else.

For example, you would need this:

```
select case
    when c IN (0, 1) AND cs IN (0, 1) AND f IN (0, 1) AND fs IN (0, 1) then
        case     
            when c=1 and cs=1 and f=1 and fs=0 then 'FPL07'     
            when c=1 and cs=0 and f=1 and fs=0 then 'FPL09'     
            else 'FPL0' + cast(c * 5 + f * 6 - cs * 2 - fs * 2 - 1 as char(1))
        end
    when Ab = 1 then 
        'FPL10'
    when cpc IN (0, 1) AND plo IN (0, 1) then
        'FPC0' + cast(cpc * 1 + plo * 2 as char(1))
    else 
        'FPL01' 
    end
```

It's condensed (sort of), but you're trading off fewer lines for less readability.

All in all, it's really not that many `WHEN` statements.

Comment: the first half of the above works, but `when ab = 1`, `when cpc IN (0, 1) AND plo IN (0, 1) then 'FPC0' + cast(cpc * 1 + plo * 2 as char(1))` or `else 'FPL01'` are selected, my result comes back as FPL0* rather than the necessary result. any ideas?

Comment: That means the math somewhere is getting truncated.  Change the `char(1)` casts to something bigger and more flexibile, possible `varchar(3)` or `varchar(5)`.

Comment: problem comes because, to return `FPL01` then `c=0 cs=0 f=0 fs=0` which satisfies `when c IN (0, 1) AND cs IN (0, 1) AND f IN (0, 1) AND fs IN (0, 1)`, thus returns `else 'FPL0' + cast(c * 5 + f * 6 - cs * 2 - fs * 2 - 1 as char(1))' rather than `FPL01`

Comment: **PROBLEM RESOLVED**: by changing `when c IN (0, 1) AND cs IN (0, 1) AND f IN (0, 1) AND fs IN (0, 1) then` to `when c=1 OR cs=1 OR f=1 OR fs=1 then`etc.